# How can I stop event bubbling for nested components dispatching a redux action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, event-bubbling

I dynamically render a bunch of nested components, all of which are also attached to a redux action.

Unfortunately, the action is being called for all of them when I click the inner most element, what can I do to stop it from bubbling under these circumstances?

Example code:

```
  <div onClick={()=>this.props.anAction(elementName)}>{elementName}
      <div onClick={()=>this.props.anAction(innerElementName)}>{innerElementName}
        <div onClick={()=>this.props.anAction(innerInnerElementName)}>    
            {innerInnerElementName}
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in `onClick` `event` and `trigger stopPropagation()`

```
<div onClick={(e)=>this.props.anAction(innerInnerElementName, e)}>    
   {innerInnerElementName}
</div>

anAction(el, ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation();
  ...
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize I could use it that way with Redux.

Thanks!